# How do I save an output from a method to use it in a different method?

Tags: java, methods, int, long-integer

Im sorry if this question has been asked a lot. Im still pretty new to programming and obviously have some issues in phrasing questions/searching for answers.

I want to do the following:

My algorithm includes 2 methods. One has the task to find out how many of the numbers between 0 to 30 are even and which one are not. I want those even numbers to be somehow stored and redirected to my second method to get added. How can I store those even numbers?

My code looks currently like this: (not even close to being finished)

```
public class Add 
{
    static long method(long end) 
    { 
      long number = even;
      return;
    }

    static long even() {
        if (i%2 == 0) { // even
        }
        else { // uneven
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[ ] args)
    {
        int number = method(30);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

edit:Im having formating problems... Im sorry the code looks even harder to understand. Im trying to fix it this instant.

Comment: please reformat your code. Code needs to be indented with 4 spaces...

Comment: Just add them to a List and pass that to your other method

Answer (score 1):

Like it was said in the comments, add them to a list, then iterate the list while updating a variable that will be the sum of the even numbers.

```
public class Add {

    private static ArrayList<Integer> evenNums = new ArrayList<>();

    private static void evenNumbers(int max) {

        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                evenNums.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> array){

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
            sum = sum + i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        evenNumbers(30);
        int sum = sum(evenNums);
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem, if it helped you, pls consider marking my answer as the correct one ;)